# Spark-Solr error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.expr.StreamExpressionParameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, solr

Have anyone tried `spark-solr` https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr

When I run this

```
val options = Map("collection" -> "DS", "zkhost" -> "url:2181,url:2181,url:2181")
val df = spark.read.format("solr").options(options).load
```

Then I get this error

```
  at solr.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:14)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:317)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.expr.StreamExpressionParameter
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 54 more
```

My setup is Ubuntu 18, Solr 7.4, Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11.12

Comment: are you using solrj jar in your project...check for it ...the class belongs to the jar...

Comment: Yes, I have that .jar `solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar` in my Solr dist/ folder.

Comment: But the project is not able to find the jar at run time...Did you create any separate project and missed adding this jar?

Comment: check your maven repo if you have this jar ...also check your project maven dependencies for this jar

Comment: Yes, you are right. The .jar from my Solrj-lib also had to be in the same .jars folder as my Spark. Then it is loading the data.
Thank you so much @AbhijitBashetti for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `solrj` lib is missing in the project.

Add the `solrj` lib as nit should work for you.